# 3rd party software to connect to AFP protocol from Winbox?

Tags: windows, mac-osx-server, afp

Is there any Windows software that will allow me to use the Macintosh AFP protocol to connect to a server?

I'm using Windows XP and Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably be better off enabling SMB on your server from Server Admin; I think you'll find this easier to deal with than trying to get your Windows machines to use AFP.

Comment: yes, but that decisions is out of my control.

Comment: plus you get strange problems with filenames and their lenght...

Answer (score 1):

every windows server comes with an option to do mac fileshareing services. you would just have do add the coresponding windows system components (was still there in win2k3 - don´t know about 2008). there are 3rd party tools aswell. [**Extrem Z IP**](http://www.grouplogic.com/products/extremeZ-IP/) is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

There was an option in older forms of Windows until OS's made after 2008. I'm still searching too. I'll let you know if I find out how. My attempts to find a third party program have come up fruitless.